# Android Insert Into SQL

Tags: php, android, sql, insert-into

I'm trying to have an Android app that submits some data to an external database, but, somehow I can't get it to work. Even with dummy data, it is not working, although no errors are shown.

sqlInsert.php (I have inserted dummy data into the string right now, wanted to see if that works).

```
    <?php

$con = $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","xxxxxxxx");

if (!$con)
  {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_select_db("medicijncheck", $con);
$medicijnid = $_POST['medicijnid'];
$dokterid = $_POST['dokterid'];
$patientid = $_POST['patientid'];
$dagmaand = $_POST['dagmaand'];
$Ingenomen = $_POST['Ingenomen'];

 $query_search = "INSERT INTO medicijncheck(medicijnid, dokterid, patientid, dagmaand, Ingenomen) VALUES('2', '2', '3', '2004/02/02', '2');
mysql_query($query_search,$con);

// if (!mysql_query($query_search,$con))
//   {
//   die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
//   }


//die(print_r($_POST));


mysql_close($con);
?>
```

The android method:

```
 public void submitMed() {

    try {
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        url2 = new HttpPost("link to sqlInsert");
        // Add your data
        nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("medicijnid", String.valueOf(MainActivity.medicijnID)));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("dokterid", String.valueOf(MainActivity.dokterNumber)));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("patientid", String.valueOf(MainActivity.patientNumber)));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("dagmaand", datum));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Ingenomen", "true"));
        url2.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        // Hier gaat ie kapot
        response = httpclient.execute(url2);
        inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();

        data = new byte[256];

        buffer = new StringBuffer();
        int len = 0;
        while (-1 != (len = inputStream.read(data)) )
        {
            buffer.append(new String(data, 0, len));
        }

        inputStream.close();
    }

    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("Nuh", "This isn't working");
    }

}
```

I'm getting a log back that the try in the trycatch failed.
Thanks a bundle!

Edit: Stacktrace:

```
05-19 15:37:47.077  19787-19787/? E/Nuh﹕ NOPE
05-19 15:37:47.077     779-1101/? E/AudioTrack﹕ AudioTrack::set : Exit
05-19 15:37:47.077  19787-19787/? W/System.err﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'org.apache.http.HttpResponse org.apache.http.client.HttpClient.execute(org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest)' on a null object reference
05-19 15:37:47.078  19787-19787/? W/System.err﹕ at com.everywhereim.nfcpoc.MedReg.submitMed(MedReg.java:55)
05-19 15:37:47.078  19787-19787/? W/System.err﹕ at com.everywhereim.nfcpoc.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:260)
05-19 15:37:47.078  19787-19787/? W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
05-19 15:37:47.078  19787-19787/? W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19748)
05-19 15:37:47.078  19787-19787/? W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    05-19 15:37:47.078  19787-19787/? W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
05-19 15:37:47.078  19787-19787/? W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
05-19 15:37:47.078  19787-19787/? W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
05-19 15:37:47.078  19787-19787/? W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
05-19 15:37:47.078  19787-19787/? W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
05-19 15:37:47.080  19787-19787/? W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
  05-19 15:37:47.080  19787-19787/? W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
```

Comment: does it get to  Log.e("Nuh", "This isn't working"); ?    
If it does, then watch what exception it throws, post the stacktrace here, etc.

Comment: Yes, it displays the error.

Comment: The error always has a stacktrace. And it has a class name. Why are you hiding it from us?

Comment: @metalurgus Where would I find said info? The logcat just throws the log out,  nothing more really...

Comment: e.printStackTrace();

Comment: Added the Stacktrace to OP. I can't understand why this is a NullPointerException though

Comment: Did you made is asynchronous,as it is a call to the internet?

Comment: MD I have now, and putting it in a separate thread got rid of the exception. However, I'm currently struggling with the PHP script, as it isn't putting stuff in the db

Answer (score -1):

I've changed the PHP code to MySQLi, and after putting my Java code in a separate thread, it worked. I just forgot to fill in some values. 
Thanks for the help all.